# C++ class that holds a set of objects

Tags: c++, class, set

So I have A class called song that works fine, now I am trying to create a class called SongLibrary that just hold a set of songs and the methods associated with that. I am having trouble getting it to work.

I feel the problem is when i initialize the set I am not quite sure what to put in the constructor.

**SongLibrary.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <set>
#include "Song.h"

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::set;

class SongLibrary
{
private:
    set<Song> m_songs;
public:
    SongLibrary();

#pragma region Getters

    set<Song> getSongs();
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Setters

    void setSongs(set<Song> songs);

#pragma endregion

#pragma region methods
    void displaySongs();
    void addSong(Song song);
```

**SongLibrary.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SongLibrary.h"

SongLibrary::SongLibrary()
{
    m_songs;
}

set<Song> SongLibrary::getSongs() 
{
    return m_songs;
}

void SongLibrary::setSongs(set<Song> songs)
{
    m_songs = songs;
}

void SongLibrary::displaySongs()
{
    for (Song song : m_songs)
    {
        song.display();
    }
}

void SongLibrary::addSong(Song song)
{
    m_songs.insert(song);
}
```

in the main i just create an instance of songs and then add some song objects to it using the songs.addSong() method. Then i try to display them unsing the display method.

The error I am getting at the moment is 
" binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Song' (or there is no acceptable conversion) "

Comment: `std::set` sorts the elements, so it requires your class to have an overload for the comparison operator(s).

Comment: Thanks, Im not entirely sure what that means but im looking into it now.

Comment: Why you don't use a simple `std::vector`?

Comment: mainly as i don't want duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `set<Song>` will initialize itself to an empty set using its own constructor, so the `SongLibrary` constructor doesn't have to do anything.

The problem you are seeing with `operator<` is that a set is only storing a single object of each `Song`. To do that it has to compare two songs to see if they are the same. So it expects the `Song` class to have a comparison operator

```
bool operator<(const Song& Left, const Song& Right);
```

that compares two songs.

An alternative to having a `set<Song>` could be to have a playlist as `vector<Song>` that doesn't care if the same song appears more than once and which doesn't require the songs to be in any particular order.